# Why is my permutation code generating duplicates?

Tags: c++

My code is generating duplicates (3) to be precise and I don't know why, could anyone help out?
I've tried searching for a problem, but to my eyes it seems the same as other premutation codes on the internet.

I was thinking it could've been a miss-use of the loop but I don't see why it's giving me 9 answers instead of 6.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(char *a, int x, int y);
void print(char *a, int n);
void permute(char *a, int n, int index);
int grabSize(char a[]);

int main() {
    char array[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; // PLACE COMPONENTS HERE
    int n = grabSize(array);

    //

    cout << "[" << endl;
    cout << "   ";
    permute(array, n, 0);
    cout << endl << "]";
}

int grabSize(char a[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

void swap(char *a, int x, int y) {
    char aux;
    aux = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = aux;
}

void permute(char *a, int n, int index) {
    if (index == n-1) {
            print(a, n);
            return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        swap(a, i, index);
        permute(a, n, index+1);
        swap(a, i, index);
    }
}

void print(char *a, int n) {
    cout << " [ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << " ] ";
}
```

Comment: You have 3 elements, and iterate recursively, so 3x3 = 9. What output do you expect/want?

Comment: You have a buffer overflow in `grabsize` by the way.

Comment: `main()` initialises `array` with three elements.   None of those elements has a value zero, and there is no guarantee that a zero will be located one past the end of the array.   `grabSize()` iterates until it finds one, and runs past the end of the array.   The behaviour is therefore undefined.

Comment: How should I go about fixing the grabSize() problem then?

Comment: In `main()` you can initialise the array with four elements, the fourth of which is a `'\0'` character.

Comment: I just implemented that, but the initial problem of printing 9 combinations instead of 6 is still unresolved, any ideas on what could be the cause of that?

Comment: The call of `permute()` with `index == 0` calls itself `n` times with `index == 1`.   Every call with `index == 1` calls itself `n` times with `index == 2` which prints the array.   Since you have `n*n` calls with `index == 2`, where `n == 3`,  the result is 9 lines of output.     To fix, you need to change how many times the loop iterates so it depends on `index`.   Initialising `i` to be `index` instead of `0` is one option (since the call with `index == 0` will call itself `3` times with `index == 1`, and each of those calls will call itself with `index == 2` twice.  3 times 2 is 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `9` combinations of string because, in `permute()`, the `for` loop variable `i` initialised with `0`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ^^^
```

Note that you are calling `permute()` function recursively to generate the permutations of string and, in every recursive call, the `index` is incremented by `1` while passing to `permute()` function but the `for` loop , in `permute()` function, starts with `0` and iterate till `< n`. Hence you are getting `n*n` combinations of string in output. Instead, the `for` loop variable `i` should be initialised with `index`:

```
    for (int i = index; i < n; i++) {
                 ^^^^^
```

Other problems in your code:

This

```
char array[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
```

is array of `3` characters. Note that there is no terminating null character in array `array`. Passing it to `grabSize()` function and checking for `'\0'` character in it will lead to UB as `grabSize()` function will end up accessing array `array` beyond its size while looking for null terminating character. To get the size of array, you can simply do `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` in `main()` function and do away with `grabSize()` function.

If you are inclined to use `grabSize()` function then either add null terminating character manually

```
char array[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

or initialise array `array` with string, like this

```
char array[] = "abc";
```

and then pass it to `grabSize()` function.

---

**Suggestion:**

In C++, the use of plain C style array is discouraged. C++ has [Containers Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), go through it. The sequence container `array` and `vector` will be of your interest.